# What's the maximum number of Kubernetes namespaces?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-namespace

Is there a maximum number of namespaces supported by a Kubernetes cluster? My team is designing a system to run user workloads via K8s and we are considering using one namespace per user to offer logical segmentation in the cluster, but we don't want to hit a ceiling with the number of users who can use our service.

We are using Amazon's EKS managed Kubernetes service and Kubernetes v1.11.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is quite difficult to answer which has dependency on a lot of factors, Here are some facts which were created on the **k8s 1.7 cluster** [kubernetes-theresholds](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/sig-scalability/configs-and-limits/thresholds.md#kubernetes-thresholds) the Number of namespaces (ns) are 10000 with few assumtions

Comment: The video linked in the page (https://youtu.be/t_Ww6ELKl4Q?t=1495) says that since K8s v1.12 that namespaces==10000 limit doesn't apply anymore. Check which K8s you are using.

Answer (score 4):

The are no limits from the code point of view because is just a Go [type](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/apis/core/types.go#L3862) that gets instantiated as a variable.

In addition to link that @SureshVishnoi posted, the limits will depend on your setup but some of the factors that can contribute to how your namespaces (and resources in a cluster) scale can be:

- Physical or VM hardware size where your masters are running

  - Unfortunately, EKS doesn't provide that yet (it's a managed service after all)
- The number of nodes your cluster is handling.
- The number of pods in each namespace
- The number of overall K8s resources (deployments, secrets, service accounts, etc)
- The hardware size of your etcd database.

  - Storage: how many resources can you persist.
  - Raw performance: how much memory and CPU you have.
- The network connectivity between your master components and etcd store if they are on different nodes.

  - If they are on the same nodes then you are bound by the server's memory, CPU and storage.

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit on number of namespaces. You can create as many as you want. It doesn't actually consume cluster resources like cpu, memory etc.